# Using SQL Server CTE to duplicate results of temporary table query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I've solved a problem I was given for work - I just solved it using temporary tables - and I'd prefer to solve it using CTEs if at all possible. Your help appreciate.

The problem is to determine convention attendance. But, the twist is, determine how many attendees have gone to the convention 3 out of the previous 5 years.

This works, the code (a little long - sorry ... ):

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 2006;
CREATE table #MeetingMatrix (MEETING varchar(10), Year Int);
CREATE table #Attendees     (Year Int, ID varchar(10));
CREATE table #RollUp        (Year Int, Matches Int);

-- Create table of meetings 
INSERT INTO #MeetingMatrix (MEETING, [Year])
SELECT MEETING, CAST(Year(END_DATE) AS Int) FROM MEET_MASTER 
WHERE MEETING_TYPE='CONV' 
  AND (Year(END_DATE) > 2000 AND YEAR(END_DATE) < 2016); 

-- Create table of EVERYONE who has gone over the years 
INSERT INTO #Attendees ([Year], ID)
SELECT DISTINCT MM.Year, Orders.ST_ID
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Order_Lines on ( Orders.Order_Number = Order_Lines.Order_Number )
INNER JOIN Product ON ( Order_Lines.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code )
INNER JOIN #MeetingMatrix MM ON PRODUCT_MAJOR=MM.MEETING
GROUP BY MM.Year, Orders.ST_ID;

-- Create yearly results desired
WHILE @cnt <= YEAR(GetDate())
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #RollUp ([Year], Matches)
  SELECT @cnt, Count(*) FROM (
    SELECT @cnt 'Year', [ID], Count(*) 'Cnt'
    FROM #Attendees
    WHERE [Year] > (@cnt-5) AND [Year] <= @cnt
    GROUP BY [ID]
    HAVING Count(*) > 2) AS R

  SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

-- display year results
SELECT * FROM #RollUp

-- clean up
```

Now this is what I have to START doing the same thing via CTE - I'm just not sure how to go through each possible year, and then determine the results for the prior 5 years (and count whether an individual attendee has gone 3 or more of those 5 years):

```
WITH MeetingMatrix AS (
  SELECT Year(END_DATE) 'Year', MEETING FROM MEET_MASTER 
  WHERE MEETING_TYPE='CONV' 
    AND (Year(END_DATE) > 2000 AND YEAR(END_DATE) < YEAR(GetDate())) 
  )

, AttendeesOverSpan AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Product.PRODUCT_MAJOR, MM.Year, Orders.ST_ID
  FROM Orders
  INNER JOIN Order_Lines on ( Orders.Order_Number = Order_Lines.Order_Number )
  INNER JOIN Product ON ( Order_Lines.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code )
  INNER JOIN MeetingMatrix MM ON PRODUCT_MAJOR=MEETING
  WHERE Orders.Status Not Like 'C%' 
    AND Order_Lines.Quantity_Ordered > 0 
    AND Product.Category in ( 'RB', 'TK' )
    AND (Lower(Product.ATTRIBUTES) <> 'comp' )
  GROUP BY Product.PRODUCT_MAJOR, MM.Year, Orders.ST_ID)

--, RollUpAttendees AS (

--)

SELECT ST_ID, Count(*) 'Cnt'
FROM AttendeesOverSpan
WHERE [Year] > 2010 AND [Year] < 2016
GROUP BY ST_ID
HAVING Count(*) > 2
ORDER BY Cnt Desc
```

Can anyone give me a clue how to proceed with the CTE path here?

All help appreciated.

Scott
Tucson, AZ

Comment: It should be quite simple to do this using outer apply to fetch the count for everyone from previous 5 years, but at least I can't figure out from your SQL how to know to which year each of the order belongs, or does each of the year have different PRODUCT_MAJOR value? Creating some sample data preferably to SQL Fiddle would help a lot.

Comment: Showing us some sample data and what the expected output should be would be helpful.

Comment: I'd have to play around a bit to get something I could post here.

The gist though, is two columns. Year and ID. If the ID has gone that Year, they're in the data. Then I'm looking to query all years, and note how many IDs have gone the last 3 of 5 years.

Comment: @Scott04073 The problem is that how to connect year and id. Id is in Orders and Year is in MeetingMatrix and as far as I can see the only link is product_major, which sounds quite strange that products and years would be linked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy:

1. In your CTE chain include a query to get all years: `,someyears as (select distinc [year] as cnt from ...)`.
2. Insteat to use your loop, join this table.

Sample:

```
SELECT cnt, Count(*) FROM (
    SELECT cnt 'Year', [ID], Count(*) 'Cnt'
    FROM AttendeesOverS inner join someyears on
  [Year] > (@cnt-5) AND [Year] <= @cnt
    GROUP BY [ID]
    HAVING Count(*) > 2) ...
```

Comment: Yep - that's what this does ...

WITH MeetingMatrix AS (
  SELECT Year(END_DATE) 'Year', MEETING FROM MEET_MASTER 
  WHERE MEETING_TYPE='CONV' 
    AND (Year(END_DATE) > 2000 AND YEAR(END_DATE) < YEAR(GetDate())) 
  )

Comment: I see you're still using the variable @cnt here - I'm trying to remove all programming if possible.

Comment: By that I mean variables / temporary tables.